# make default customOptions property in the Date/Time Component JSON + FormIoJS

Tags: javascript, odoo, formio

I have installed the following module in Odoo Community 15.0 version.
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/formio/

I am using a Date/Time Component on multiple forms.

I think the default behavior of Date/Time component UI is like below:

- Default view on desktop like below screenshot.

[image]

- But in Mobile (Mobile Web Brwoser) show the default Android date/time view.

To make it consistent I have used below options in the Component JSON

```
"customOptions": {
   "disableMobile": true
}
```

Main Question: How can I add this customOptions to all Date/Time component by default?
currently, I need to add this option manually to all Date/Time Components (Already created and even newly created Date/Time component)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @joaorodr84 Not so far.